# How can I extract 8 letter capital word from a sentence in a cell in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Example - Sentence in Cell `A1` is `WO# 000000.0 for ITSHTJ in Q0 20000_ITAI0006:TBD Replacement PO` and I want to extract `ITAI0006`.

I have used below UDF but it's not helpful.

```
Function findUcase(Rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim Txt
    Dim Desc() As String

    Desc = Split(Rng.Value, " ")
    For Each Txt In Desc
        If (UCase(Txt) = Txt) Then
            findUcase = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: @braX till now i have tried below function but it doesn't work for 8 letter word                     Function findUcase(Rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim Txt
    Dim Desc() As String

    Desc = Split(Rng.Value, " ")
    For Each Txt In Desc
        If (UCase(Txt) = Txt) Then
            findUcase = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function

Comment: @SiddharthRout i have mentioned my approach, please help out

Comment: Can you give few more examples on how your text looks like? and what do you want to extract from it?

Comment: @RaymondWu i have mentioned the code in question too, please check

Comment: @shailzachaudhary So how is your code not helpful? Do you want the function to return the string instead of a boolean? Is the requirement that the string must be 8 characters?

Comment: With the equality operator `=`, VBA compares strings case insensitively by default, therefor,the `Ucase(txt) = txt` always returns `true`. You might want to try `StrComp(Ucase(txt), txt, vbBinaryCompare)` instead.

Comment: @SiddharthRout in a cell i have long text like  Subcontracted consulting services for Acrylic major ltd. (XYWRTVSD) - Custom CLOUD AA- as per say and am willing to extract only 8 letter capital word

Comment: What if there are two words that meet the requirement of capitals and 8 characters long?

Comment: I would recommend posting few sample in your question :)

Comment: @trincot no that's not the case with dataset i have. This 8 character capital letter occurrence in once only.

Comment: What if there is a word with 9 capital letters? Should it be ignored? Or would you get the first 8 characters of it? Or all 9?

Comment: Hmmm. no answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," "),":"," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length(.)=8][translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', '')='']")
```

Where the XPath expressions filter nodes on:

- `[string-length(.)=8]` - All substrings of 8 characters long;
- `[translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', '')='']` - Make sure that when all uppercase alphachars and numbers are substituted with nothing, the node would also equal nothing.

---

Note that a formulae-approach can get much simpler once you have more specific rules down, e.g.:

- Is it always the 8 characters before the first colon?
- Is it always between underscore and colon?
- Is it always alphanumeric?
- Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Regex method - This will return any 8 characters (A-Z and numbers) from the given cell.

```
Function findUcase(Rng As Range) As String
    If Rng.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Dim regex As Object
        Set regex = CreateObject("vbScript.Regexp")
        
        regex.Global = False
        regex.Pattern = "[\dA-Z]{8}"
        If regex.Test(Rng.Value) Then
            findUcase = regex.Execute(Rng.Value)(0)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

**Edit** - Another version that will return string that has at least `A-Z` in the string and also supports format of 8 characters of any amount of A-Z, a space then any amount of numbers.

```
Function findUcase(Rng As Range) As String
    Const firstPattern As String = "[\dA-Z]{8}"
    Const secondPattern As String = "[A-Z]+ [\d]+"
    Const charLimit As Long = 8
    
    If Rng.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Dim rngValue As String
        rngValue = Rng.Value
        
        Dim regex As Object
        Set regex = CreateObject("vbScript.Regexp")
        
        Dim matchColl As Object
        Dim match As Object
            
        regex.Global = True
        regex.Pattern = firstPattern
        If regex.test(rngValue) Then
            Set matchColl = regex.Execute(rngValue)
            
            For Each match In matchColl
                If Not IsNumeric(match) Then
                    findUcase = match
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next match
        Else
            regex.Pattern = secondPattern
            If regex.test(rngValue) Then
                Set matchColl = regex.Execute(rngValue)
                For Each match In matchColl
                    If Len(match) = charLimit Then
                        findUcase = match
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next match
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    Set matchColl = Nothing
    Set regex = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What when there are capitalised words with more than 8 characters?

Comment: If OP's dataset is as shown then this issue might not happen. At this point I'm not sure how to handle text in brackets (as shown by OP in comment)

Comment: @RaymondWu thanks alot, it helped but its not working for sentence like  WO#12344050.0 for ENG ID ABEFPQRS: Start Date  5/4/2021 milestones, code is returning numeric value i.e. 12344050 and how can to include space in regex method as i have few more 8 letter characters to extract for example:  CD 00001, ASI 1234

Comment: @shailzachaudhary It seems that you are neither stating your criteria properly nor giving enough examples of different permutations. By including space in regex, you are opening to more false positive. `WO# 000000.0 for ITSHTJ in Q0 20000_ITAI0006:TBD Replacement PO` will return " ITSHTJ " as it fulfills the condition as well. Same for `Subcontracted consulting services for Acrylic major ltd. (XYWRTVSD) - Custom CLOUD AA` - returns " CLOUD A ".

Comment: @shailzachaudhary I have updated answer with another version, please try the edited version.